# Filtering list and returning only the items with matching criteria, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am filtering list items in an object in a directive like so:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attr, controller) {
  var matches = {};
  var original = clone(controller.items);
  scope.$on('ecal:searchbox-valuechanged', function (event, message) {
    for(var key in original) {
      if (coriginal.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        for(var i=0; i < original[key].length; i++) {
          if (original[key][i].name.indexOf(message.data.search) >= 0) {
            matches[key] = original[key];
          };
        }
      }
    }
    controller.items = matches;
  });
  function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
  }
}
```

The problem with this, is that `controler.items` initially is empty, and waiting for service to update its data, when the directive is compiled, the `original` variable is empty, thus cloning it is useless.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do it in a callback: `scope.$watch("controller.items", callbackFunction)`

Comment: which one should I be putting inside the callback?

Comment: The part of the code that should wait until there is data available